Can I change the names of the column headers in my look?
If you look at this screenshot, you can see the "repetition" of the header names. "Company Id Company Id" etc...

This is the LookML for company id dimension:
  dimension: company_id {
    view_label: "Company Id"
    label: "Company Id"
    description: "Seller's company name"
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.company_id ;;
  }

Is there a way to stop that and have only one single header name ie
"Company Id Year Month..." ?

This can be done in the Visualisation tab, you can just disable the "Show Full Field Name" toggle.

